# Altair Layer Chart Y Axis Not Resolving to Same Scale

Tags: python, altair

I'm trying to plot data and compare it to a threshold set at a fixed value. When creating a [`layer`ed](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/compound_charts.html#layered-charts) chart, the y axis does not appear to hold for both layers. The same goes for [`hconcat`](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/compound_charts.html#horizontal-concatenation).

I found [this issue](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1298) which mentions `.resolve_scale(y='shared')`, but that doesn't seem to work. When I specify the rule to be at 5, it appears above 15.

```
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.linspace(0, 10, 500),
    'y': np.random.randn(500).cumsum()
})

base = alt.Chart(df)
line = base.mark_line().encode(x='x', y='y')
rule = base.mark_rule().encode(y=alt.value(5))

alt.layer(line, rule).resolve_scale(y='shared')
```

[image: layered chart incorrect display]

To get the rule to appear at the value 5, I have to set it at 110.

```
rule = base.mark_rule().encode(y=alt.value(110))

alt.layer(line, rule).resolve_scale(y='shared')
```

[image: layered chart incorrect value]

How can I edit the chart so that the rule shows at the y-value specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altair scales map a *domain* to a *range*. The *domain* describes the extent of the data values, while the *range* describes the extent of the visual features to which those values are mapped. For color encodings, the range might be `"red"`, `"blue"`, `"green"`, etc. For positional encodings like `x` and `y`, the range is the pixel position of the mark on the chart.

When you use `alt.value`, you are specifying the range value, not the domain value. This is why you can use an encoding like `color=alt.value('red')`, to specify that you want the mark to appear as the color red. When you do `y=alt.value(5)`, you are saying you want the mark to appear 5 pixels from the top of the y-axis.

Recent versions of Vega-Lite added the ability to specify the domain value via `datum` rather than `value`, but unfortunately Altair does not yet support this, and so the only way to make this work is to have a data field with the desired value. For example:

```
line = base.mark_line().encode(x='x', y='y')
rule = alt.Chart(pd.DataFrame({'y': [5]})).mark_rule().encode(y='y')

alt.layer(line, rule).resolve_scale(y='shared')
```

[image]

Comment: Jake, Thanks for the clarification. I was wondering why the value of 110 was so much lower than 5, but pixel position makes a lot of sense. I was hoping to make it work without creating a DataFrame for a single value, but it's not a big deal if that's the way to go. While I am lucky enough to have your audience, I want to say thanks for all your work in making Altair a nice tool for the rest of us to use. I've been really enjoying the package and find it more readable than some of the other plotting packages.